# Custom ViewEngine with custom pages extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i created a custom View Engine for handling mobile requests. These views must have ".mobile" extension and have to be placed under /ViewsMobile root folder:

```
public class MobileViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public MobileViewEngine()
        {
            MasterLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/ViewsMobile/Shared/{0}.mobile" };
            ViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/ViewsMobile/{1}/{0}.mobile", "~/ViewsMobile/Shared/{0}.mobile" };
            PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/ViewsMobile/Widgets/{1}/{0}.mobile" };
            FileExtensions = new string[] { "mobile" };
        }
        public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
        {
            ViewEngineResult result = null;
            var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

            if (request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
            {
               result = base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, false);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

i inserted this ViewEngine in ViewEngines.Engines at position 0 (to be the top engine) in `Application_Start` event.

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, new MobileViewEngine());
```

After i added this line into web.config in order to recognize the .mobile extension:

```
 <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".mobile" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
 </buildProviders>
```

Now, if im accessing a home page (controller=pages, action=main) from a mobile platform im getting the following exception:

> Could not determine the code language for "~/ViewsMobile/Pages/Main.mobile". Crashes on line `base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, false);`

Here's the stack trace:

> [InvalidOperationException:Could not determine the code language for
>   "~/ViewsMobile/Pages/Main.mobile]
>   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.GetCodeLanguage()+24401
>
> System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost..ctor(String virtualPath,
>   String physicalPath) +136
>
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory.CreateHost(String virtualPath,
>   String physicalPath) +43 ....

Do you know how i can use a custom extension for my views like ".mobile" and use Razor inside each one?

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards.

Jose.

Comment: I think you cannot do anything here because WebPageRazorHost need to know the language. Try, mobile.cshtml or mobile.vbhtml or create custom build provider which use custom razor host. Take a closer look at MVC 4 Source

Comment: Okay i think i will use file name instead extension. Thanks